# Finding a Resource Text File

Tags: objective-c, resources, xcode4

Just to begin, I've read [Read text file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034113/read-text-file-in-a-folder) and other troubleshooting things on here, and I've followed the advice previously given.

However, my program still can't find my .txt file.

I've checked the name, the bundle resources, and the file itself, and everything seems to be in order. My code runs fine, and I get my own error message when it can't find the file. No crashes or anything out of the ordinary.

I've also changed the Preferences/Locations/Build Location to "Place Build Products in locations specified by targets." which was an issue before.

Any additional help?

Thanks in advance!

```
    #import "FileArrayControl.h"


@implementation FileArrayControl

@synthesize partArray, arrayContent;

- (NSArray *) setFileToArray {

    NSString *stemFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stemList.txt" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"stemIDv0"];

    if (stemFile != nil) {

        // ...stuff...


    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error, file not found!");
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",partArray);
    return partArray;
}


@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incorrectly using `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:`. This method should not include the extension in the first parameter. So it would be:

```
NSString *stemFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stemList" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"stemIDv0"];
```

Comment: Okay, I fixed that, but it's still not working. Thanks though, that probably would have caused problems later on.

Comment: Is stemIDv0 in your project as a folder reference? If it is a normal folder, then it will not be created and stemList.txt will be put directly in Resources. You must make it a Folder Reference for Xcode to copy the actual directory. You can check by building this for the Simulator and then going into the bundle to see where stemList.txt is located.

Comment: Now that I have permission to post images, I think it would be easier for me to show you where it is. I checked in the bundle while running the Simulator, and it seems to be under stemIDv0 like it should be.

Comment: Hrrrmmm. I found the problem. But now I have a different bug. I seem to have been looking in the wrong file(?). I need to look in Frameworks for the current build information (I was looking in my project folder).